# How to get tooltip/click index of highchart graph in objective-c code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, highcharts, uiwebview

I am using Highcharts in my Native iOS app and loading them using UIWebView. I am able to pass the data from Objective-C to javascript function. But, vice-versa is not getting feasible.
Highcharts provide tooltip/click, when we click on any data presented in the graph. I want to track which tooltip is clicked so that I can re-direct it to other screen accordingly. 
To get a hold of that click, I am trying to use JavascriptCore framework provided by Apple and calling the function "sendObjcClickAction" from javascript.
Please refer my code below:
Objective-C:

> JSContext *context =  [webView
>   valueForKeyPath:@"documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext"];
>
> ```
> context[@"sendObjcClickAction"] = ^(id obj) {
>
>     NSLog(@"GET CALLBACK :: %@", obj);
> };
> ```

Here, it does not go inside the condition. Don't know whether the problem is in my "valueForKeyPath" or not. Because the mainFrame array that I received has zero objects.

Javascript/jQuery:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Highcharts Example</title>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
${demo.css}
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
function temp(array, array2) {
  
  
    $('#container').highcharts({
                               
        chart: {
            type: 'area'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Historic and Estimated Worldwide Population Distribution by Region'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: Wikipedia.org'
        },
        scrollbar: {
            enabled: true
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['1750', '1800', '1850', '1900', '1950', '1999', '2050','2100'],
            tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
            title: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Percent'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b> ({point.y:,.0f} millions)<br/>',
            shared: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            area: {
                stacking: 'percent',
                lineColor: '#ffffff',
                lineWidth: 1,
                marker: {
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    lineColor: '#ffffff'
                }
            }
        },
     series: [{
         name: 'Asia',
         data: [502, 635, 809, 947, 1402, 3634, 5268]
     }, {
         name: 'Africa',
         data: [106, 107, 111, 133, 221, 767, 1766]
     }, {
         name: 'Europe',
         data: [163, 203, 276, 408, 547, 729, 628]
     }, {
         name: 'America',
         data: array2
     }, {
         name: 'Oceania',
         data: array
     }]
                               
    });
  
  
}
function sendLoginAction()
{
    sendObjcClickAction(this.series.data.indexOf( this.point ));
}
    </script>
 </head>
 <body>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; max-width: 800px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am wondering if it is possible to use plotOptions.point.events.click event callback function and inside it use your function. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.area.point.events.click
Right now I cannot find any place where you are using it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. And how do I send that point to my Objective-C file every time I click a column in the UIWebView?